# JDBC cannot login to LocalDB instance, but in SSMS I can log in

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, authentication, connection

I am trying to connect to my database by JDBC on localhost. Connecting via windows authentication is no problem, but I want to connect via SQL authentication. Therefore, I created a login and a user corresponding to this login in my database. I can normally log in SSMS:

[image: log by the user in SSMS]

My connection string for JDBC: 
`jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=TestBazyDanych;user=doszke;password=doszke123`

Thrown exception:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'doszke'. ClientConnectionId:b7005fe3-904d-40c5-a89e-af0cb61250d6
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:254)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:258)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:104)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:4772)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3581)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServerConnection.java:81)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3541)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7240)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2869)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2395)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2042)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1889)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1120)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:700)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:251)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:38)
```

The username and password are the same, as those used for loging to SSMS.

Here my class code:

```
package main;

import java.sql.*;

public class Main {


    private static ResultSet selectStan(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        String sql_stmt = "SELECT * FROM STAN;";
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(sql_stmt);
        System.out.println("Select executed");
        return result;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {



        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        String userName = "doszke";
        String password = "doszke123";

        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=TestBazyDanych;user=doszke;password=doszke123";


        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url)) {

            if(con != null){
                System.out.println("connected");
            } else {
                System.out.println("unable to connect");
            }

        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: The screenshots shows you are connecting to a LocalDb instance which just uses your Windows credentials IIRC. As I pointed out on your previous question, JDBC doesn't support LocalDb. And if you want to connect with your Windows credentials, then you need to use integrated authentication or Kerberos authentication.

Comment: I have found a solution. Connecting to localDb with JDBC is possible, but I needed to instal jTDS in order to create a connection. Also I added name pipe to my connection string. `jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://./TestBazyDanych;instance=LOCALDB#EB7165FD;namedPipe=true`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As **Mark Rotteveel** pointed out, I was trying to connect to a LocalDB instance with JDBC, which seemed undoable. (ref: [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/769))

However, I installed jTDS and added to my classpath, changed my connection string to

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://./TestBazyDanych;instance=LOCALDB#EB7165FD;namedPipe=true
```

create a connection by the use of this connection string, username and password and it worked. The instance pipe number was taken from cmd line via

```
sqllocaldb i MSSQLLocalDB
```

Answer (score 0):

***There are few things need to check:***

1. Did you create **doszke** user under the database and SSMS?
2. Are you able to login with **doszke/doszke123** credentials in SSMS?
3. Please check 1433 port are open or not in your inbound and outbound firewall.
4. Trying to **telnet on localhost 1433**. If it's getting failed change below setting:
   Go to Configuration tools -> SQL Server Configuration Manager Select SQL Server Network Configuration -> Select protocol in the right side window enable tcp/ip and restart the services in services.

Comment: User "doszke" is created under my database for login "doszke" for the server. I am able to login to my databse with "doszke"- that is on the screen. I have enabled all ports. Now I will check the wirewall, this is the only thing I hadn't done.

Comment: I disabled the firewall for a while and it did not help.

Comment: Try to lenlent on localhost 1433. if it's getting failed change below settings in SSMS: Go to Configuration tools -> SQL Server Configuration Manager Select SQL Server Network Configuration -> Select protocol in the right side window enable tcp/ip and restart the services in services.

Comment: All Tcp/Ip were enabled